# Copy CoreData data to CSV file

Tags: swiftui, ios15

I am trying to use fileExport logic to copy history data from CoreData to a CSV file. Since the data is coming from CoreData I need to use **@FetchRequest** and it is my understanding that @FetchRequest may only be used in a view.

I'm getting a number of errors related to misusing a view and transferring the data to fileExporter. It seems like I'm misusing a view to transfer data. Are there other features of CoreData that can be used to retrieve data outside of a view?

I have several similar structures that create CSV files without using coreData working.     Therefore I believe my structures CreateHistoryTable and MessageDocument are working correctly. So I need help getting my data from CoreData to fileExporter.

```
struct CreateHistoryTable: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext

    @State private var showingExporter: Bool = false
    @State private var document: MessageDocument?

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Button ( action: {
                self.showingExporter = true
                document = CreateHistoryCSV() <-- need help here retrieving document to export

            }) {
                HStack (alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
                    Text("Export History Entries")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .font(.title3)
                    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                }
            }
        }.fileExporter(
            isPresented: $showingExporter,
            document: document,
            contentType: .plainText,
            defaultFilename: "TripSenseHistory.csv"
        ) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let url):
                print("Saved to \(url)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Export History Entries"), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

Retrieve data from CoreData and copy to single text string

```
struct CreateHistoryCSV: View  { 
     @Binding MessageDocument


    var csvData: String = ""
    var title = ",Trip Sense History Entries,\n"

    var subtitle = "Date,Category,Payment Type, Amount\n"
    var messageRow: String = ""
    var sHisCatName: String = ""
    var sHisDsc: String = ""
    var sHisPayType: String = ""
    var sHisMoney: String = ""
    var dHisMoney: Double = 0.0
    var sHisLoc: String = ""
    var payType = ["Cash", "Debit", "Credit"]
    var code: String = ""
    var messageRow = ""

    // fetch core data
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: CurrTrans.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \CurrTrans.entryDT, ascending: true)]
    ) var currTrans: FetchedResults<CurrTrans>

    var body: some View {

        var csvData = title + subtitle

        for item in 0..<currTrans.count {

            let messageRow = createHistoryRow(item: item)
             csvData += messageRow
        }
        print(csvData)
        //return MessageDocument(message: csvData)
    }
```

```
    func createHistoryRow(item: Int) ->(String) {

        // format expense date and time
        let dHisDate = currTrans[item].entryDT ?? Date()
        let sHisDate = dHisDate.formatted(.dateTime.year().day().month(.wide).hour().minute())

        // get history category
        let sHisCatName = currTrans[item].entryCatName ?? "cat name"

        // get payment type
        let sHisPayType = payType[Int(currTrans[item].entryPT)]

        // get description
        let sHisDsc = currTrans[item].entryDsc ?? "Unk"

        // format transaction amount
        let code = currTrans[item].entryCode ?? "Unk"  // 3 digit country code for this transaction
        let dHisMoney = currTrans[item].entryMoney
        let sHisMoney = dHisMoney.formatted(.currency(code: sym))

        // get location
        let sHisLoc = currTrans[item].entryAddr ?? "Unk"

        messageRow = "\"\(sHisDate)\"" + "," + sHisCatName + "," + sHisPayType + "," + "\"\(sHisDsc)\"" + "," + "\"\(sHisMoney)\"" + "," + "\"\(sHisLoc)\"" + "\n"

        return messageRow
    }
}
```

This code is part of the Swiftui file export logic

```
struct MessageDocument: FileDocument {

    static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] { [.plainText] }

    var message: String = ""

    init(message: String) {
        self.message = message
    }

    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        guard let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents,
              let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
        }

        message = string
    }
    // this will be called when the system wants to write our data to disk
    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        return FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: message.data(using: .utf8)!)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can request the data with a standard Swift Core Data `FetchRequest`. It is similar to an `@FetchRequest`, but works everywhere. There are tons of resources on it.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll look into that

Comment: All that I found was @FetchRequest, not FetchRequest even when searching Apple's documentation

Comment: `NSFetchRequest` is a one time pull of CoreData objects, no observing.

Comment: This kind of loop `for item in` shouldn't be in a `body` the `body` gets recreated at the discretion of SwiftUI as many times as it deems necessary.

Comment: [A top 3 return](https://www.advancedswift.com/fetch-requests-core-data-swift/) for "Swift FetchRequest", though "Swift Core data fetch request" would probably be a better search term...

Answer (score 1):

With further research I realized that I could place the @FetchRequest in CreateHistoryTable along with the fileExporter view logic. That allowed me to change CreateHistoryCSV to a function of CreateHistoryTable. No changes were made to createHistoryRow

```
// copy history entrys to csv file
struct CreateHistoryTable: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var base: BaseCurrency
    @EnvironmentObject var bank: BankWithdrawal
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext

    @State private var showingExporter: Bool = false
    @State private var document: MessageDocument?

    var title = ",Trip Sense History Entries,\n"
    var subtitle = "Date,Category,Payment Type, Amount\n"
    var messageRow: String = ""
    var sHisCatName: String = ""
    var sHisDsc: String = ""
    var sHisPayType: String = ""
    var sHisMoney: String = ""
    var dHisMoney: Double = 0.0
    var sHisLoc: String = ""
    var payType = ["Cash", "Debit", "Credit"]
    var sym: String = ""

    // fetch core data
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: CurrTrans.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \CurrTrans.entryDT, ascending: true)]
    ) var currTrans: FetchedResults<CurrTrans>

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Button ( action: {
                self.showingExporter = true
                let dates = userData.formatCsvDate(startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate)
                document = CreateHistoryCSV(dates: dates)

            }) {
                HStack (alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
                    Text("Export History Entries")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .font(.title3)
                    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                }
            }
        }.fileExporter(
            isPresented: $showingExporter,
            document: document,
            contentType: .plainText,
            defaultFilename: "TripSenseHistory.csv"
        ) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let url):
                print("Saved to \(url)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Export History Entries"), displayMode: .inline)
    }

func CreateHistoryCSV() -> (MessageDocument) {

        var csvData = title + subtitle

            for item in 0..<currTrans.count {

            let messageRow = createHistoryRow(item: item)
            csvData += messageRow
        }
        print(csvData)
        return MessageDocument(message: csvData)
    }
```